# Push view down using Crouton library

Tags: android, view, crouton

I'm using the Crouton library on Android to display some notifications.  https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

I want the notification to push the existing view down instead of being overlaid with the crouton.  Is this possible using this library?

Comment: No, you should use something like this to achieve the results you require https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the SuperToasts library that MrEngineer13 posted about.

Answer (score 0):

The [Android Design Support](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) library is probably what you're looking for. Specially the [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) seems of interest for your needs.